# How to filter the pandas dataframe using the 'not equal to' function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying the filter a pandas dataframe by using != operator. I want to filter the table by removing 'Falcon 1' from the 'BoosterVersion' row and I have been using this to run the code,

```
data_falcon9 = df[df['BoosterVersion'] != 'Falcon 1']
```

But every time I ran into an error, `KeyError: 'BoosterVersion'`

[image]

Comment: keyerror means the key is not in your dataframe.
try df.columns to see the actual names of the columns. probably a typo or some auto conversion occured when you loaded the file

Comment: You're right. I investigated and realized that I messed up the previous line of code and the values in the table for rows and columns were inverted, therefore the following code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**BoosterVersion** not a column. try:

```
data_falcon9 = df.T  #transpose
data_falcon9 = data_falcon9 [data_falcon9 ['BoosterVersion'] != 'Falcon 1']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data_falcon9 = df.T #or df.transpose()
```

this will transpose your dataframe and make BoosterVersion a columns that's why it was giving you key error.

```
#now you can filter it
data_falcon9 = data_falcon9 [data_falcon9 ['BoosterVersion'] != 'Falcon 1']

#if you want the original dataframe transpose again
df_without_falcon1 = data_falcon9.T #or data_falcon9.transpose()
```